# Is there any way to push Widget above of the Keyboard when it shows up?

Tags: flutter, dart, keyboard, focus

I uses TextFormField with Scrollable parent, when the keyboard shows up, is there any way to have the Widgets to be above the keyboard? Is it FocusNode that I should be using?

[Current Situation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYEqP.gif)

From this, you can see that when my keyboard shows up, the Button will be covered.

Comment: In this case I added the package Keyboard visibility and made a block the size of the keyboard appear below my form when it is opened, it did the trick quite well

Comment: Interesting suggestion! I tried out @Tolga 's answer and it worked. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can, just put all widgets which needs to stay over the keyboard in a SingleChildScrollView,  and set reverse property of the SingleChildScrollView to true

Comment: Wow! It works like a charm. May I know why is it setting to *reverse* will result in that? I thought setting reverse is changing the way it scrolls? Care to brief me on this? Thanks!